# How to remove a varying string from a set of other, longer strings?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Background information: Directory `c:\documents` is full of `.doc` and `.xls` files from different people. There are put in initials somewhere in the filename in order to identify who edited the file. Every filename may have one or more of initial sets. I am only interested in `.doc` files this time. A cross section of this directory is looking like this:

```
depot.inventory.20180921.[CMP]-[OxA](DOT)-(TTR).edited.doc
rack_location_(IIY)collected.2018.11.24.edit[UTS]_{POM}.doc
```

The list goes on and on for hundreds of files. I want to generate a copy of these files without the editors´ initials and put them into a directory called `c:\uniform`.

The constants here are: every set of initials are 3 letters long and can be upper or lower case and enclosed in some sort of brackets. At any given time, I have a list of editors´ initials in a file one set per line format, such as:

```
CMP
OXA
TTR
DOT
UTS
IIY
POM
```

The file has about 100-150 names on any given day.

I figured out so far how to remove one set of initials from all `.doc` files as follows:

```
for /R "C:\documents" %%f in (*.doc) do (
    call :Sub %%~nf
)

:Sub
set str=%*
set str=%str:[DOT]=%
echo %str%
```

Here, in this code segment, I put `[DOT]` as an example. I want to make the string `[DOT]` a variable and read it from the editors´ initials file. However, this is necessary for each document file many times.

So my batch program is going to loop thru all *.doc files in source directory, for each file, it will go thru a loop of 100-150 names and remove those strings and form a new filename and copy the old file from source directory, into the destination directory, with the new filename, which is the editors´ initials stripped off version of the source filename.

How can I do the second loop?

I am stumped at the syntax.

Comment: Given your examples, it appears that you're expecting your 'uniform' filenames to be, `depot.inventory.20180921.--.edited.doc` and `rack_location_collected.2018.11.24.edit_.doc`. Is that correct? and if so why?

Comment: Are you sure that you're working with `.doc` and `.xls` files? You are aware that this has not been the default filetype for Microsoft Office since Word/Excel 2003. You may not think that this is a particularly important question, but `(*.doc)` in your code parses `.doc`, `.dochtml`, `.docm`, `.docmhtml`, `.docx`, `.docxml` etc. too!

Comment: @compo I am not using DOS per-se but I am using DOS cmd on a win-7 pro workstation, which is my laptop. I am not sure about how this this naming convention came to be but I am trying to help a family friend, who is totally computer illeterate, other than double-clicking files and obviously, tracking who edited the file thing is of no interest to this person.Your assumption of final file name is correct for the time being, but the plan is, after removal of initials, I will try to use the same method to eliminate the extra dots, dashes and underscores and whatnot. This is just a start.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commented batch file for this unusual file copying task.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=C:\documents"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\uniform"

rem Is there no *.doc file to process in source directory?
if not exist "%SourceFolder%\*.doc" goto :EOF

rem Do nothing if the text file with editors' initials
rem does not exist in the batch file directory.
if not exist "%~dp0EditorsInitials.txt" goto :EOF

rem Create the destination directory on not already existing
rem and veriy the real existence of the destination directory.
md "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul
if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" goto :EOF

rem Read the editors' initials from text file and create a space separated
rem list of them assigned to the environment variable EditorsInitials.

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "EditorsInitials="
for /F "usebackq" %%I in ("%~dp0EditorsInitials.txt") do set "EditorsInitials=!EditorsInitials! %%~I"
endlocal & set "EditorsInitials=%EditorsInitials:~1%"

rem For each non-hidden *.doc file in source directory get file name with
rem file extension and with path if there is one specified left to *.doc
rem and assign it to the environment variable FullFileName. The file name
rem only is assigned to the environment variable FileName. Then delayed
rem environment variable expansion is enabled again for running two nested
rem loops which runs case-insensitive string substitutions on the file name
rem string value to remove the editors' initials from the file name. Next
rem one more loop is used to remove also .edited and .edit from file name.
rem The current *.doc file is finally copied with cleaned file name to
rem the configured destination directory. A date in file name remains.

for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%\*.doc") do (
    set "FullFileName=%%I"
    set "FileName=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%J in (%EditorsInitials%) do for %%K in ("-" "." "_" "") do (
        set "FileName=!FileName:%%~K[%%J]=!"
        set "FileName=!FileName:%%~K(%%J)=!"
        set "FileName=!FileName:%%~K{%%J}=!"
    )
    for %%J in (".edited" ".edit") do set "FileName=!FileName:%%~J=!"
    copy "!FullFileName!" "%DestinationFolder%\!FileName!%%~xI" >nul
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

This batch file executes the command `copy` with the file `EditorsInitials.txt` in directory of the batch file containing posted list of editors' initials for the two example *.doc files with the arguments:

```
"C:\documents\depot.inventory.20180921.[CMP]-[OxA](DOT)-(TTR).edited.doc" "C:\uniform\depot.inventory.20180921.doc"
"C:\documents\rack_location_(IIY)collected.2018.11.24.edit[UTS]_{POM}.doc" "C:\uniform\rack_locationcollected.2018.11.24.doc"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the full path of the directory containing this batch file always ending with a backslash.
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul` and `2>nul`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a regex in PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, it will have PowerShell. This does assume that no one uses a VERTICAL LINE as part of their initials nor as a bracket around initials. Change the `$DestinationDir` to your choice.

When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

=== Rename-Initials.ps1

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\src\t\reninitials'
$DestinationDir = 'C:\src\t\reninitials\uniform'
$Editors = (Get-Content -Path $(Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath 'Editors.txt')) -join '|'
$OpeningBrackets = @('\[', '\(', '{') -join '|'
$ClosingBrackets = @('\]', '\)', '}') -join '|'
$Regex = '(' + $OpeningBrackets + ')(' + $Editors + ')(' + $ClosingBrackets + ')'
$FileTypes = @('*.doc', '*.xls')

foreach ($FileType in $FileTypes) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDir -File -Recurse -Filter $FileType |
        ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.Name -match $Regex) {
                $NewName = $_.Name -replace $Regex,''
                Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName `
                    -Destination $(Join-Path -Path $DestinationDir -ChildPath $NewName) -WhatIf
            }
        }
}
```

If you must call it from a cmd.exe shell:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "Rename-Initials.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The task you are trying to accomplish is not that trivial, particularly when you do not want to leave sequences of separators, like periods, hyphens, underscores, etc., after removal of the parenthesised string portions.

Here is a script that removes the parenthesised known editors' initials (predefined in a list file `initials.txt` in the current directory) one after another; if two adjacent separators (like `.`, `-`, `_`, and also `,`, `;`, `%`) would be left behind, the first one is removed; if no such would be there, the one defined first (`.`) is inserted. Optionally, a potential tail consisting of a known suffix (like `edited` or `edit` as defined in the script) and a preceding separator becomes removed too. So this is the code, including some explanatory `rem` remarks:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\documents" & rem // (root directory; `.` is current, `%~dp0.` is script's parent)
set "_DEST=C:\uniform"   & rem // (destination directory)
set "_OVER="             & rem // (set this to `|` to overwrite existing files, or else to ``)
set "_LIST=initials.txt" & rem // (text file containing list of editors' initials, one per line)
set _MASKS="*.doc" "*.xls" & rem // (list of file patterns to process)
(set _LF=^
%= blank line =%
) & rem // (line-break)
set _PAREN=( )^%_LF%%_LF%[ ]^%_LF%%_LF%{ } & rem // (list of pairs of parentheses)
set _SEPAR=. - _ "," ";" %% & rem // (list of separators; do not use `=`, `~`, `!`, `^`)
set _TAILS="edited" "edit"  & rem // (optional list of suffixes to remove; may be empty)

rem // Change into root (source) directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Iterate through all matching files:
    for %%F in (%_MASKS%) do (
        rem // Store full name of current file:
        set "FILE=%%~F" & set "NAME=%%~nxF"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Loop over the list of initials:
        for /F "usebackq delims= eol=|" %%E in ("%_LIST%") do (
            rem // Loop over trailing separators:
            for %%J in (. !_SEPAR! "") do (
                rem // Loop over leading separators:
                for %%I in (!_SEPAR! "") do (
                    rem // Loop over pairs of parentheses:
                    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%K in ("!_PAREN!") do (
                        rem // Conditionally remove parenthesised text from file name:
                        if not "%%~J"=="" (
                            set "NAME=!NAME:%%~I%%K%%E%%L%%~J=%%~J!"
                        ) else if not "%%~I"=="" (
                            set "NAME=!NAME:%%~I%%K%%E%%L%%~J=%%~I!"
                        ) else if defined _SEPAR (
                            set "NAME=!NAME:%%~I%%K%%E%%L%%~J=%_SEPAR:~,1%!"
                        ) else (
                            set "NAME=!NAME:%%~I%%K%%E%%L%%~J=.!"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Process optional list of suffixes:
        if defined _TAILS (
            rem // Use `for /F` loop to split file name into base name and extension:
            for /F "delims= eol=|" %%N in (""!NAME!"") do (
                endlocal
                rem // Store file name components:
                set "NAME=%%~nxN" & set "EXT=%%~xN" & set "TEST=%%~nN|"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Loop over suffixes:
                for %%M in (!_TAILS!) do (
                    rem // Loop over separators:
                    for %%J in (!_SEPAR!) do (
                        rem // Remove found suffix from base name:
                        if not "!TEST!"=="!TEST:%%~J%%~M|=!" (
                            set "NAME=!TEST:%%~J%%~M|=!!EXT!"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Actually copy file to destination with the newly built name:
        if not exist "!_DEST!\!NAME!!_OVER!" (
            ECHO copy /Y "!FILE!" "!_DEST!\!NAME!"
        )
        endlocal
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Configure the exact behaviour in the section `Define constants here:` at the top.

After having tested the output, remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually copy files; to suppress numerous lines `1 file(s) copied.` returned by the `copy` command, replace that `ECHO` by `> nul` instead.